# Trying to run mongorestore and cannot connect?

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoAtlas and trying to run mongorestore and I am getting the following error.

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

I am using the command Atlas proposes.

```
mongorestore --host BStaging-shard-0/bstaging-shard-00-00-lq11i.mongodb.net:27017,bstaging-shard-00-01-lq11i.mongodb.net:27017,bstaging-shard-00-02-lq11i.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username heroku --password "VN" --authenticationDatabase admin 
2019-04-14T11:02:31.336-0500    

Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

1. Updated MongoDB community Shell
2. Changed bash_profile to point to new shell
3. Changed bash_profile to point to new mongo db community4.0

   (/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community-shell/bin:$PATH)
4. source bash_profile
5. reconnect to mongo

   mongo "mongodb://staging-shard-00-00-dgdr.mongodb.net:27017,staging-shard-00-01-dgdr.mongodb.net:27017,staging-shard-00-02-dgdr.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Staging-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username me --password pwd
6. restore

   mongorestore --host Staging-shard-0/staging-shard-00-00-dgdr.mongodb.net:27017,staging-shard-00-01-dgdr.mongodb.net:27017,staging-shard-00-02-dgdr.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username me --password pwd --authenticationDatabase admin